# FB.ui callback function gets called before sharing happens on facebook.issue is related with IE and squarespace?

Tags: internet-explorer, modal-dialog, facebook-sharer, squarespace

i have implemented facebook share button functionality into my website and it is working fine with chrome and firefox.I have build my website into squarespace.The problem is related to internet explorer when i am trying to share, a modal box appears and gets closed/replaced by chrome's modal box at the same time callback function gets called and displays the sharing failed message.when i click on cancel button modal box becomes blank and does not get disappear as it should.when we click on share sharing happens but callback function does not get call and modal box does not get disappear.

i am surprised to get chrome's modal and alert into internet explore.when i tried the same code out of squarespace it works. It seems squarespace is serving chrome's alert and modal and when ie's modal box appears(for some miliseconds).it gets closed(and replaced with chrome's modal box) by squarespace that is why callback function gets a call.

here is my code...thankyou for any help..:)

```
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Audio track 00',
        link: '',
        caption: 'Bombay Rockers',
        description: 'By XYZ',
        message: ''
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert('sucessfully shared...:)');
            } else {
                alert('some error occured while posting.please retry');
            }
        });
    });
```